# JQuery adding class not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm a little new to JQuery, so forgive me if this is obvious.

I'm running this code to add/remove an "active" class to fixed nav bar list items as the user scrolls up and down a single page. It's working in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Anybody know why?

Thanks!

```
// #div ids for page content
$(this).ready(function(){
var section0Height = $('#home').height();
var section1Height = $('#mission').height();
var section2Height = $('#services').height();
var section3Height = $('#team').height();
var section4Height = $('#contact').height();


// #li ids for nav items
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winTop >= section0Height && winTop <= section1Height){
        $('#section0').addClass("active").not().removeClass("active");
    } else if(winTop >= section1Height && winTop <= section2Height){
        $('#section1').addClass("active").not().removeClass("active");
    } else if(winTop >= section2Height && winTop <= section3Height){
        $('#section2').addClass("active").not().removeClass("active");
    } else if(winTop >= section3Height && winTop <= section4Height){
        $('#section3').addClass("active").not().removeClass("active");
    } else if(winTop >= section4Height){
        $('#section4').addClass("active").not().removeClass("active");
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the `.not()` in there for?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that works in Chrome and IE. Without any arguments, `.not()` shouldn't do anything, meaning it's just adding and then immediately removing the "active" class from whichever section is supposed to be highlighted.

Comment: Also, `.height()` should provide the height of the object, rather than the distance from the top of the window, which is what I'd imagine you want. Could you please provide a working example on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what it's meant to do?

Comment: Not sure what the .not() in there was for. I adapted this from another bit of code. I made a crude version of what I'm trying to achieve at http://jsfiddle.net/mrilikecoding/TR9Fb/ but this doesn't seem to work at all. The idea of course is that when the user scrolls to a particular section of the page, the corresponding navigation link changes to "active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TR9Fb/1/) based on the one you provided. Basically, instead of looking for the height of the div, you need to find the offset from the top of the document. When the window is scrolled down to that div then `$(window).scrollTop()` will match up with `$(section).offset().top`. The fiddle has some more comments to explain different parts, but here's the code for quick reference:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var links = $('#section0, #section1, #section2, #section3');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        $.each(links.removeClass('active').get().reverse(), function (idx, link) {
            var section = $( $(link).attr('href') );
            if (winTop >= section.offset().top) {
                $(link).addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
$(this).ready(function(){ ...
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ...
```

[jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the
>   current document

Other than the fact that `not()` without a parameter, does nothing for you, it's the only reason I can spot for the posted code not to work?

Comment: Or even simpler, `$(function(){ ... });`